# Выбор слитного или раздельного написания частицы НЕ: кто и когда это решает?

Tags: частица-не

Уважаемые участники форума! Мне хотелось бы обсудить с вами этот вопрос,   предложив свою версию ответа.

Вот перед нами готовое предложение: **Его место рождения неизвестно.** Нам кажется, что мы управляем его содержанием: выберем слитное написание НЕ ― получим утверждение, а выберем раздельное написание НЕ ― получим отрицание.

Но ведь форма написания НЕ в устной речи не отражается, и тогда получается, что наш "выбор" ― это выбор фиктивный. **На слух это предложение будет восприниматься как утвердительное**, потому что **его структура  и грамматика уже заданы**, а  именно они определяют (и уже определили), утверждение это или отрицание.

**Чтобы выразить отрицание, автор текста должен изменить его структуру,** добавив, например,  усилительное слово: **Его место рождения никому не известно.**

Можно изменить порядок слов и выбрать предикативное наречие: **Не известно, где именно он родился.** В начале предложения **при логическом ударении** частица НЕ  воспринимается как отрицательная, что отражается не только на письме, но и в устной речи.

Таким образом, в структуре предложения (или в контексте) должна **присутствовать подсказка о том, что это отрицание, в противном случае мы воспринимаем предложение как утвердительное.** Это автор выбирает и решает, а ученик на письме "угадывает" уже готовое авторское решение по каким-то признакам.

Но мы так не думаем, мы считаем следущим образом: **"Все зависит от того, хотите ли вы утверждать неизвестность или отрицать известность"**. Или другой вариант: **"Оба написания возможны. Зависит от вкладываемого смысла"**

**Нет, с готовым текстом мы уже ничего утверждать не можем, и смысл в него заложен автором.** А если мы сами пишем текст, то должны вложить в него однозначность прочтения, выбрав соответствующую форму предложения.

Comment: Ну... есть такой термин: амфиболия. "Я любил и женщин, и проказы: что ни день, то новая была" О чём (или о ком) идёт речь во второй строчке? Как и любая другая фигура речи, амфиболия бывает намеренной, а бывает случайной, ухудшающей восприятие смысла. Конечно пишущий должен стараться избегать ненамеренной двусмысленности. Но если уж так получилось, мы выбираем вариант на свой вкус, в значительной мере случайно.

Comment: Какое это все, простите, имеет отношение к вопросу?